# Multiple Azure blob versions with reduced size

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading log files to Azure from an application. I am seeing multiple versions of the same
“.log” file with the size being reduced over the period of one hour.

A file that started out as 1.1Mb is reduced to 54 bytes over 11 versions!

Everybody on my team claims to not be reading or writing those log files and the files are uploaded once and deleted from storage on another device.

Is there some way that I can find out what is creating the versions of a log file?

I’ve never seen this behavior. We use Azure blob storage a lot.

I have looked for other writers or readers of these blob files.

Comment: Provide the code how you are uploading so that the community can check in more detail

Comment: I can’t do that. 

I will find the method in the SDK that I used to upload a blob. That has uploaded millions of blobs without producing versions of the file as I explained here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way that I can find out what is creating the versions of a log file?

Here there are multiple versions of the same log file are created with reduced sizes over time in Azure Blob Storage, I have modified the provided Python script.

**Code:**

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContentSettings
import time
import random
import string

# Define your Azure Storage account details
account_name = 'your_storage_account_name'
account_key = 'your_storage_account_key'
container_name = 'your_container_name'

# Create a BlobServiceClient using the storage account credentials
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Create the blob container if it doesn't exist
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
container_client.create_container()

# Define a function to generate random log data
def generate_log_data(size):
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=size))

# Define the filename and path for the log file
log_file_name = 'sample_log_file.log'

# Define the initial size of the log file
initial_size = 1100000  # 1.1 MB in bytes

# Define the number of iterations to simulate
num_iterations = 11

# Upload the log file to Azure Blob Storage and modify it multiple times
for i in range(num_iterations):
    # Generate random log data with reduced size over time
    log_data = generate_log_data(initial_size // (2 ** i))

    # Upload the log file to Azure Blob Storage
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_file_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(log_data, overwrite=True, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='text/plain'))

    print(f"Iteration {i + 1}: Uploaded log file with size {len(log_data)} bytes")

    # Simulate a delay before the next iteration
    time.sleep(3600)  # 1 hour delay
```

- The size of the log file is reduced by half in each iteration by dividing the initial size (1.1 MB) by 2.
- The script uploads the log file to Azure Blob Storage every hour (3600 seconds) for 11 iterations, simulating the reduction in size over time.

**Log file:**

[image]

**Blob Size:**

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand how this helps me. Somehow, our file is being reduced in size but nobody says they’re writing out multiple versions of the file.